# How to configure the cmake file correctly to build a simple hello world for nlohmann_json?

Tags: c++, cmake, nlohmann-json

I am using the following JSON parser: https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Following is the steps I followed to build :

```sh
 2074  git clone https://github.com/nlohmann/json.git
 2075  git branch
 2076  ls
 2077  cd json/
 2078  git branch
 2079  git pull
 2080  ls
 2081  vi CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md 
 2082  mkdir build
 2083  cd build/
 2084  ls
 2085  cmake ..
 2086  cmake --build .
 2087  ctest --output-on-failure
```

The unit tests pass. I do not see the library being built, as the documentation mentions.

I am trying to build a simple hello world program for the parser.
Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include<string.h>
// for convenience
using json = nlohmann::json;

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ifstream ifs("test.json");
    json jf = json::parse(ifs);
     return 0;
}
```

And the CMake file:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name
project(my_json CXX)
find_package(nlohmann_json 3.2.0 REQUIRED)
```

However, CMake cannot find the package nlohmann_json.

Please suggest how to build this example.
I am planning to use the external library method to build this code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide the **full** CMake log, including the error message, that you see when trying to configure your CMake file.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow. I am not getting an option to add a file. How do I provide the logs?

Comment: Just use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60607037/edit) button. Copy/paste the *text* of the log/error messages into your question post.

Comment: the log file is too big for stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 3):

### Package Approach

The default behavior of `find_package` is expecting to find the package installed on your system.

If you have a simple local clone, then you should provide a `Find***.cmake` file in your module path, which matches the module name.

For example, make a file called `Findnlohmann_json.cmake` with some contents like this:

```
if( TARGET nlohmann_json )
  return()
endif()

if(NOT NLOHMANNJSON_ROOT)
  set(NLOHMANNJSON_ROOT "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/json")
endif()

add_library( nlohmann_json INTERFACE )
target_include_directories(
  nlohmann_json
  INTERFACE
    ${NLOHMANNJSON_ROOT}/include
)
```

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure for more info.

### Local Source Approach

That said, if you are keeping the library in your source tree, you might find it easier to simply call `add_subdirectory` from your project's `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(my_json CXX)
add_subdirectory( lib/nlohmann_json )

//...
target_link_libraries( myApp PRIVATE nlohmann_json )
```

Be aware that not all libraries are ready to be included in this fashion